# Reference request: The first cohomology of SL(2,Z) with coefficients in homogeneous polynomials 

Tags: reference-request, group-cohomology, nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Let $H_k$ be the vector space of degree $k$ homogeneous polynomials in two variables.I'm looking for a reference for the fact that $H^1(SL(2,\mathbb Z);H_k)=M^0(k+2)\oplus\overline{M^0(k+2)}\oplus E_{k+2}$, where

1. $M^0(k+2)$ is the space of cuspidal modular forms of weight $k+2$.
2. $\overline{M^0(k+2)}$ is its conjugate.
3. $E_k$ is $1$-dimensional if $k\geq 4$ is even, and is zero otherwise.

I know how to get the $M^0(k+2)\oplus\overline{M^0(k+2)}$ piece. By the Eichler-Shimura isomorphism, this is the same as the cuspidal cohomology $H^1_{cusp}(SL(2,\mathbb Z);H_k)$, spanned by cocycles that vanish on the matrix $T$=[1 1 \ 0 1].  Serge Lang's book on Modular Forms has a detailed explanation of how to get this. I'd really like to know how to get the $E_{k+2}$ piece, which as far as I understand, corresponds somehow to the Eisenstein series, which is the "extra" modular form of weight $k+2$ that is not cuspidal.

It's not too hard to see that $H^1(SL(2,\mathbb Z);H_k)=H^1(PSL(2,\mathbb Z);H_k)$, with $PSL(2,\mathbb Z)$ having the nice presentation $\langle S,T\,|\, (ST)^3=S^2=I\rangle$, so one should be able to represent the $E_{k+2}$ cocycle by specifying its values on $S,T$.

So, to summarize, I'd be satisfied with any proof that $H^1(SL(2,\mathbb Z);H_k)=M^0(k+2)\oplus\overline{M^0(k+2)}\oplus E_{k+2}$, but I'd be happiest with an answer that lets me get my hands on the $E_{k+2}$ cocycle as explicitly as possible, perhaps even telling me its values on $S$ and $T$. Any comments that would help clarify this are appreciated.

**Edit:** I think I have a better understanding of what the "extra" Eisentstein cocycle is, based on Kevin's comments. It seems that the cuspidal cocycles vanish on $T$, whereas the Eisenstein cocycle vanishes on $S$, although I don't see how to show, for example, that there is only one dimension's worth of cocycles vanishing on $S$, up to coboundaries. (**Edit**: I'm not entirely sure about this.)

**Edit:** Shimura's *Introduction to the Theory of Automorphic Forms* only covers the cuspidal part of the above isomorphism.

Comment: Given the Eisenstein series $E(\tau)$ as a function on the upper half plane, isn't the cocycle you want simply the standard one: given $\gamma$ you integrate $\tau^n E(\tau)$ from $i$ to $\gamma i$ for $0\leq n\leq k$ and patch these $k+1$ numbers together into an element of $H_k$ in the standard way as in e.g. Shimura's book?

Comment: I know that for cuspidal forms $f(z)$ you integrate $f(z)z^s$ from $0$ to $\gamma 0$ to get a cocycle. I guess you're saying I should do a similar thing, but not use a boundary point. 

Comment: @Kevin: which book of Shimura are you referring to? 

Comment: You can integrate from $z$ to $\gamma z$ for any $z$ in the extended upper half plane to get a cocycle, and different choices will change the cocycle by a coboundary. I can't see where you are assuming that the form is cuspidal when doing this integration, at least if $z$ is in the upper half plane. As far as I know Shimura only wrote one book---his introduction to the theory of automorphic forms. But you seem to know the construction for cusp forms anyway. I don't understand what your question is really. Doesn't the same trick work for the Eisenstein series? If not why not? Sorrytobeconfused.

Comment: Shimura has written several books. There were at least five in our library and a cursory glance did not reveal anything to do with cocycles or cohomology. 

I agree that taking any $z$ in the upper half plane and integrating $z$ to $\gamma z$ will give a cocycle for any modular form, but you can't get enough of them this way. To get most of them, you have to start with a point on the boundary, such as $0$, but this construction only seems to be well-defined for cuspidal forms. 


Comment: 
The basic reason is that the cocycle you mentioned,  integrating from $i$ to $\gamma\cdot i$, vanishes on $S$, which means it can't be nonzero for a cuspidal cycle, which vanishes on the other generator $T$.

Comment: Apologies for being behind in the amount of books Shimura has written. I'm talking about his "introduction to the arithmetic theory of automorphic functions" which surely explains everything although I don't know this for sure. I don't really understand most of what you're talking about though :-( You make comments like "you can't get enough of them this way"---your statement of the Eichler-Shimura isomorphism above says exactly that all cohomology classes come, in some way, from modular forms. I also don't understand "to get most of them...boundary". I wish someone would come in with a...

Comment: ...more readable reference because I'm sure one can do better than Shimura in this day and age.

Comment: I looked up Shimura's book. It was a sixth book that someone had checked out. It only covers the cuspidal case.

Comment: I am not an expert of the subject, but maybe the things you are after are *modular symbols* (of level 1), especially those whose pairings with cuspidal forms (holomorphic and anti-holo) vanish. Recent references are William Stein's book "Modular forms, a computational approach" AMS 2007, or Manin's article http://www.claymath.org/publications/Arithmetic_Geometry/Manin.pdf in "Arithmetic Geometry" CMI/AMS publication 2009.


Comment: I should add that these *symbol spaces* are homological, rather that cohomological, hence should be "dual" to your (or Shimura) spaces. And that the exposition in Stein's book is based on Loic Merel '94 paper available at its home page, as well as an article in press on the subject.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The result you're looking for is contained in the following article :

Haberland, Klaus. Perioden von Modulformen einer Variabler and Gruppencohomologie I (German)  [Periods of modular forms of one variable and group cohomology I], *Math. Nachr.*  **112** (1983), 245-282.

Let $S_k$ (resp. $M_k$) be the space of holomorphic cusp forms (resp. holomorphic modular forms) for $\Gamma = SL_2(\mathbf{Z})$. Let $\Gamma_{\infty}$ be the stabilizer of $\infty$ in $\Gamma$. Let $V_k$ be the space of polynomials of degree $\leq k-2$ with complex coefficients. Haberland proves an exact sequence

\begin{equation}
(*) \qquad  0 \to S_k \oplus \overline{S_k} \to H^1(\Gamma,V_k) \to H^1(\Gamma_\infty,V_k) \to 0.
\end{equation}
Let $T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \in \Gamma_{\infty}$. There is a natural map $V_{k+1} \to H^1(\Gamma_\infty,V_k)$ sending a polynomial $P$ to the cocycle $c_P$ determined by $c_P(T) = P(X+1)-P(X)$. It is easy to check that this map induces an isomorphism $\psi : V_{k+1}/V_k \cong H^1(\Gamma_\infty,V_k)$, so that the latter space is one-dimensional.

The "Eisenstein cocycle" you're looking for is a natural map $\delta : M_k \to H^1(\Gamma,V_k)$ which Haberland constructs the following way (actually I learnt this construction and many other properties of $\delta$ during Zagier's 2002-2003 lectures at the Collège de France).

Let $f \in M_k$. Let $\widetilde{f}$ be an Eichler integral of $f$, that is any holomorphic function on $\mathcal{H}$ such that

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{1}{2\pi i} \frac{d}{dz}\right)^{k-1} \widetilde{f}(z) = f(z).
\end{equation}
Note that $\widetilde{f}$ is unique up to adding some element of $V_k$. Since we integrate $k-1$ times, the function $\widetilde{f}$ should be thought of as a function of "weight" $k-2\cdot (k-1) = 2-k$ (of course this isn't true in the strict sense). Let us make this more precise.

For any $n \in \mathbf{Z}$, let $|_n$ denote the weight $n$ action of $SL_2(\mathbf{R})$ on the space of complex-valued functions on $\mathcal{H}$ (so that any $f \in M_k$ is a fixed vector of the weight $k$ action of $\Gamma$). Note also the weight $2-k$ action gives the usual action of $\Gamma$ on $V_k$. The crucial fact is that we have

\begin{equation}
\widetilde{f} |_{2-k} (\gamma-1) \in V_k \qquad (\gamma \in \Gamma).
\end{equation}
This can be proved using Bol's identity

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{d}{dz} \right)^{k-1} (F |_{2-k} g) = \left(\frac{d^{k-1} F}{dz^{k-1}} \right) |_k g
\end{equation}
which holds for any holomorphic function $F$ on $\mathcal{H}$ and any $g \in SL_2(\mathbf{R})$.

Since $\gamma \mapsto \widetilde{f} |_{2-k} (\gamma-1)$ is obviously a coboundary in the space of functions on $\mathcal{H}$, it defines a cocycle in the space $V_k$. Therefore we get $\delta(f) \in H^1(\Gamma,V_k)$ and this element doesn't depend on the choice of $\widetilde{f}$. Thus we have constructed $\delta : M_k \to H^1(\Gamma,V_k)$.

It is not difficult to check that if $f =\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n e^{2i\pi nz}$ then the image of $\delta(f)$ in $H^1(\Gamma_\infty,V_k)$ is the image of the polynomial $\frac{a_0 \cdot (2\pi i)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} \cdot X^{k-1} \in V_{k+1}$ under the isomorphism $\psi$ above. In particular $\delta$ is injective, and the exact sequence $(*)$ gives the isomorphism you want.

Note that there is a distinguished choice of $\widetilde{f}$, namely

\begin{equation}
\widetilde{f} = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a_n}{n^{k-1}} e^{2i\pi nz} + \frac{a_0 \cdot (2\pi i)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} z^{k-1}.
\end{equation}
Let $c_f \in Z^1(\Gamma,V_k)$ be the cocycle associated to this choice of $\widetilde{f}$. Let us compute the value of $c_f$ on $T$ and $S= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. First as explained above, we have

\begin{equation}
c_f(T)=\frac{a_0 \cdot (2\pi i)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} ((X+1)^{k-1}-X^{k-1}).
\end{equation}
To compute $c_f(S)$, Haberland uses the natural integral representation of $\widetilde{f}$ in terms of $f-a_0$, and gets

\begin{equation}
c_f(S) = \frac{(2\pi i)^{k-1}}{(k-2)!} \int_0^{\infty} \left(f(z)-\frac{a_0}{z^k}-a_0 \right) (z-X)^{k-2} dz
\end{equation}
(there is a similar but more complicated formula for $c_f(\gamma)$ for any $\gamma \in \Gamma$, see below). Then $c_f(S)$ can be expressed in terms of the special values of $L(f,s) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n/n^s$ at integers $s = 1,\ldots,k-1$. It is then a good exercise to compute $c_f(S)$ when $f$ is the Eisenstein series $E_k$, in terms of Bernoulli numbers and of $\zeta(k-1)$ (this is Satz 3 in Haberland's article, Kapitel 1).

Please tell me if something isn't clear in my explanation.

EDIT : I found the following expression for $c_f(\gamma)$ where $\gamma \in \Gamma$. It is quite complicated (maybe it could be somewhat simplified) :

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{(k-2)!}{(2\pi i)^{k-1}} c_f(\gamma) &= \int_{z_0}^{\infty} (f(z)-a_0)(z-X)^{k-2} dz + \int_{\gamma^{-1} \infty}^{z_0} \left(f(z) -\frac{a_0}{(cz+d)^k} \right) (z-X)^{k-2} dz \\
& + \frac{a_0}{k-1} \left((X-z_0)^{k-1}-(X-\gamma z_0)^{k-1} |_{2-k} \gamma + X^{k-1} |_{2-k} (\gamma-1) \right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $z_0 \in \mathcal{H}$ is arbitrary and $\gamma= \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Sorry, it seems that my LaTeX code is wrong, and I don't know how to fix it... Doesn't "pmatrix" work here ?

Comment: I should also add that there is indeed an "integral representation" of the cocycle $r_f$, as Kevin Buzzard initially suggested. But I am not sure yet of the exact shape of the formula. So if I have time I will try to do the computations and then complete my answer.

Comment: There is a bug in the software that occasionally makes it choke on some code like pmatrix.  You can work around the problem by enclosing the LaTeX in "accent grave"s.

Comment: @Francois: I appreciate your detailed answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to edit my LaTeX code. Thanks a lot also for the tip, now I think I will manage to write matrices on MO!